# Passing Query Data Params in get HTTP request

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk, reducers

So, the back-end of my Recipe generate App's Get HTTP endpoints accept params and manipulate the response based on the params passed in the routes.

For example: if I want to receive recipes belong to only certain cuisine groups, I can pass those cuisine groups in my get HTTP request

```
"http://myrecipe.com/get/recipes/?cuisine=mediterranean&&cuisine=indian&&cuisine=chinese
```

here is my action.js

```
export const getRecipes = (params, access_token) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(
          '/api/recipes'), 
          { params: {} }, 
          {headers: Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`}
     ); 
   dispatch({
       type: GET_RECIPES,
       payload: res.data
   }); 
}
```

and my component:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getRecipes({params: {cuisine: 'indian', cuisine: 'chinese', cuisine='mediterranean'} }, user.access_token); 
}
```

but this doesn't seem to be working, whats wrong with my code??

Comment: As @user2343647 mentioned, are you using redux-thunk?

Comment: yes, I am using redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. Use redux-thunk or redux-saga (I recommend the latter) for asynchronous calls.